# Click event on element div except child

Tags: javascript, jquery, bootstrap-4

I have a list which contains text to the left and an image to the right. 
I want to make a click event when clicking on the list element it triggers code but when clicking on the image on the same element it did't trigger the code.

```js
$('.list-group').on('click', '[data-toggle="lightbox"]', function(event) {
  event.preventDefault()
  $(this).ekkoLightbox()
})
$('.list-group').on('click', '.list-group-item', function(e) {
  if ($(this).hasClass('active')) {
    $(this).removeClass('active')
    $(this).closest('.input').find('input').click()
  } else {
    $(this).addClass('active')
    $(this).closest('.input').find('input').click()
  }
})
```

```css
.img-fluid{
  height: 150px;
  width: 150px;
}
.list-group-item{
  cursor:pointer;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
<ul class="list-group">
  <li class="list-group-item d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center">
    <div class="">
      Cras justo odio
    </div>
    <a
      href="https://p.bigstockphoto.com/rwyznvNQ76U2liDFDH6g_bigstock-Yachts-In-City-Bay-At-Hot-Summ-283784740.jpg"
      data-toggle="lightbox"
    >
      <img
        class="rounded float-right img-fluid"
        src="https://p.bigstockphoto.com/rwyznvNQ76U2liDFDH6g_bigstock-Yachts-In-City-Bay-At-Hot-Summ-283784740.jpg"
        alt="..."
    /></a>
  </li>
</ul>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ekko-lightbox/5.3.0/ekko-lightbox.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: What do you mean by `it triggers code`. What should happen when you click where. I tried your code and clicked on both the listitem and the image and as a result the background changes the color.

Comment: It should add active class and save its status to the localsorage but the problem is that when click on the image it adds the active class and opens image popup, all I want to do is to exclude image from li click event

Comment: would you like to add an 'active' class if an image is clicked?

Comment: Add active class if list element is clicked anywhere except the image

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I made an example below.

https://codepen.io/pglejzer/pen/wvaJQLe

```js
$(".list-group").on("click", '[data-toggle="lightbox"]', function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  if (!$(".list-group .list-group-item").hasClass("active")) {
    $(this).ekkoLightbox();
  }
});

$(".list-group").on("click", ".list-group-item", function(e) {
  if ($(e.target).hasClass("active")) {
    $(e.target).removeClass("active");
    $(this)
      .closest(".input")
      .find("input")
      .click();
  } else {
    $(e.target).addClass("active");
    $(this)
      .closest(".input")
      .find("input")
      .click();
  }
});
```

```css
.img-fluid{
  height: 150px;
  width: 150px;
}
.list-group-item{
  cursor:pointer;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" />

<ul class="list-group">
  <li class="list-group-item d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center" >
    <div class="">
     Cras justo odio
      </div>
    <a  href="https://p.bigstockphoto.com/rwyznvNQ76U2liDFDH6g_bigstock-Yachts-In-City-Bay-At-Hot-Summ-283784740.jpg" data-toggle="lightbox">
  <img class="rounded float-right img-fluid" src="https://p.bigstockphoto.com/rwyznvNQ76U2liDFDH6g_bigstock-Yachts-In-City-Bay-At-Hot-Summ-283784740.jpg" alt="..."></a>

  </li>
</ul>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ekko-lightbox/5.3.0/ekko-lightbox.min.js"></script>
```